# XCode 10 adding action to button

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a Cocoa app with buttons that run simple command line scripts.
I can't seem to figure out how to add the action to my button.
I've read some docs that suggest holding down option and dragging the button into controller code but I think they are out of date.
 Can someone suggest how to get there from this screenshot?
[image]

Comment: How about addTarget method of Button?

Comment: Did you tried right click in mouse ? or else tried connection inspector?

Comment: Should be ctrl left click or just the right click and then drag it into the controller. Make sure you assigned the controller to the screen or it will not work (little yellow button on top of the layout, there you can assign your class)

Comment: You don't ask Google or Yahoo about IBAction NSButton?

Comment: When I try to drag the button into the code pane it just slides back.

Comment: Can you show a picture of the identity inspector of `Document.xib`?

Comment: Xcode is simply a poorly implemented bad design. A question like this exemplifies the problem with Xcode usability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to first select your button, then hold the `control ⌃` button on your keyboard and then drag that across to your view controller. That will then give you the option of what to name your method etc.

[image]

Comment: Ok I got that working. It gave me `@IBOutlet weak var a1:NSButton!` at the top of Document class. But that's just a declaration, how do I add action?

Comment: Do that again and in the little window that comes up, you can select a different "Connection" action.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same problem and the root cause was just the drag method. From the descriptions I had assumed that I need to press CTL and then drag while having the left mouse button pressed. This did not work at all (in my environment). Then I noticed that "it works" with the right mouse button. But the result was not correct. (E.g. I could not get "Action"). Finally I found: I have to use the right mouse button only for dragging without holding CTL. Then I got the correct result.